# user authentication linkedin -

Tags: python, api, python-requests, linkedin-api

I am trying to authenticate in linkedin api to scrape some data from individual and company profiles. I am terribly confused with the OAuth2.0 documentation provided by developer.linkedin.com. I am not sure if I am using correct api calls for access data points. For an instance, I want profile of many users theirs work history, etc. But before I hit it, how do I authenticate the user to make api calls? I used following bud does not work-

```
client_id ='.....'

client_secret='.....'
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'

linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri='https://127.0.0.1')
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)
authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)

print 'Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url

redirect_response = raw_input('Paste the full redirect URL here:') 
#here I add https://127.0.0.1

linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
    authorization_response=redirect_response)

r = linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~')  
print r.content
```

I followed Tutorial from here: `https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/master/docs/examples/linkedin.rst`

here is the message when I enter - https://127.0.0.1 as the terminal requests its.

```
python ~/linkedin.py
Please go here and authorize, https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=777m76reoggue0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1&state=bo91J8MNuMTx1WQWn9nLd5kgGbZYFE
**Paste the full redirect URL here:https://127.0.0.1**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/linkedin.py", line 22, in <module>
    authorization_response=redirect_response)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 187, in fetch_token
    state=self._state)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/web_application.py", line 174, in parse_request_uri_response
    response = parse_authorization_code_response(uri, state=state)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 227, in parse_authorization_code_response
    raise MissingCodeError("Missing code parameter in response.")
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MissingCodeError: (missing_code) Missing code parameter in response.
```

Comment: Can you please include any relevant libraries or error messages?

Comment: hi andrewgu, sorry got prematurely posted. Updated

Comment: Did you register that `redirect_uri` while creating your connected app on LinkedIn?

Comment: @lpt was my answer helpful ?

Comment: @laguittemh, I had that accomplished the goal and your answer is great. I wanted more like how to extract data, I am not worried about UI level authentication. Can you point me to any resources on that? Basically say extract thousands of user profiles and export to csv. Any note on that?

Comment: Hi @lpt, your question is about user authentication. I answered that. If you found the answer useful, a thumbs up and/or accepting would be great. If you have further questions, post them in a different post maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- you registered http://127.0.0.1 as an **Authorized Redirect URLs** with your linkedin app
- you paste the full redirect URL that you get in your browser with the `?=code` parameter in my case it looked like:

  In[19]: redirect_response

  Out[19]: 'https://127.0.0.1/?code=AQQyB2NCpL5iE_wyOqmqTm5z......iKhx#!'
- you paste that URL with HTTPS and not HTTP